# How do you show multiple error messages specific per row of an XML import?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, data-tables, error-message, data-entry

Currently, I'm working on an **import function** **to migrate users** from one system to our system.

I've checked the post input, and there is a possibility that there can be 39 error messages per person. In the MVP, they don't want to make the import editable. The business only wants to show what goes well and what goes wrong.

So, the idea is as follows:

[image: 1. A simple import function;]

[image: 2. Upload file]

[image: After import, you will be shown how many users are imported successfully and not that successful ;-).]

So, I wonder. Is this the best way of showing this kind of error message? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can a user import the incorrect data? And can they fix the errors on this screen, and if yes, please provide some examples and scenarios on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the user to address the errors, and just want to show what happened, a fairly common pattern is to show a message like this at the end of the process:

> [filename.csv] was imported with 39 errors. [Download error report](https://#)

The error report shows each line that had an error, with an explanation of the error. It downloads as its own CSV file, which can be opened later, or by someone else who is responsible for correcting data errors. Then you're not making your user take screen shots or copy/paste the problems into another file for correction.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 39 errors is too much. You will have to think first how to reduce the number of errors on this screen. There are multiple ways to do this. You can guide your users before they import a file. It may be a short video tutorial, a help page, or you may give them the demo file option so they can download and see how to manage your file correct way before they importing the file.

Comment: First, thanks for your fast reply. Maybe, it's good to refer to the helpdesk where there is more info about this topic of importing data from another resource (because it's not that of regular action. It only happens once if users migrate from our competition to ours. A video is an excellent option to do!